# Device connects to HotSpot with ASCII SSID, but not when given name with foreign UTF-8 letters

Tags: utf-8, wifi, ssid, wpa-supplicant

and thanks to this wonderful forum!

I'm developing a device that runs Linux embedded using wpa-supplicant.
I must be able to connect to any Wifi network with any SSID - including symbols and foreign characters.
I've been learning about UTF-8 encoding and experimenting with all types of names for SSID.

When the HotSpot on my Android is called **123=Mechi_abc**, the device connects:

```
Oct  3 07:17:42.222 **wpa_cli scan_results**  
Selected interface &apos;wlan0&apos;  
bssid / frequency / signal level / flags / ssid  
b2:22:7a:91:85:e5       2437    -75     [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS][P2P]  DIRECT-E5-HP OfficeJet Pro 8020  
20:58:69:63:89:48       2462    -80     [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][ESS]  
20:58:69:23:89:48       2462    -79     [ESS]   Leumi_Guest  
20:58:69:a3:89:48       2462    -82     [ESS]   Plazma  
**8a:18:94:1d:e9:0f       2462    -21     [ESS]   123=Mechi_abc**  

Oct  3 07:17:42.333 **wpa_cli set_network** 4 ssid &apos;"**123=Mechi_abc**"&apos;

Oct  3 07:17:42.506 **wpa_cli list_networks**  
Selected interface &apos;wlan0&apos;  
network id / ssid / bssid / flags  
0       MYEYE_AUTO      any     
1       Plazma  any     
2       Leumi_Guest     any     
4       **123=Mechi_abc**   any

Oct  3 07:17:43.104 **wpa_cli select_network** 4

Oct  3 07:17:43.169 **wpa_cli status**  
Selected interface &apos;wlan0&apos;  
wpa_state=DISCONNECTED  
ip_address=192.168.72.3  
p2p_device_address=34:e1:d1:a7:19:62  
address=34:e1:d1:a7:19:62  
uuid=9f4c27f1-a49d-5486-8821-465bc569b9ea


Oct  3 07:17:43.184 **wpa_cli list_networks**  
Selected interface &apos;wlan0&apos;  
network id / ssid / bssid / flags  
0       MYEYE_AUTO      any     [DISABLED]  
1       Plazma  any     [DISABLED]  
2       Leumi_Guest     any     [DISABLED]  
4       123=Mechi_abc   any
   

Oct  3 07:18:07.067 **wpa_cli status**  
Selected interface &apos;wlan0&apos;  
bssid=8a:18:94:1d:e9:0f  
freq=2462  
ssid=**123=Mechi_abc**  
id=4  
mode=station  
pairwise_cipher=NONE  
group_cipher=NONE  
key_mgmt=NONE  
**wpa_state=COMPLETED**  
ip_address=192.168.72.3  
p2p_device_address=34:e1:d1:a7:19:62  
address=34:e1:d1:a7:19:62  
uuid=9f4c27f1-a49d-5486-8821-465bc569b9ea


Oct  3 07:18:07.100 **wpa_cli list_networks**  
Selected interface &apos;wlan0&apos;  
network id / ssid / bssid / flags  
0       MYEYE_AUTO      any     [DISABLED]  
1       Plazma  any     [DISABLED]  
2       Leumi_Guest     any     [DISABLED]  
4       **123=Mechi_abc   any     [CURRENT]**
```

When the name of the Android HotSpot is "**123מכיabc**" (123 + 3 Hebrew letters + abc) - UTF-8 - **123\xd7\x9e\xd7\x9b\xd7\x99abc** (which is viewed correctly with Hebrew letters using an iPhone).

The network is found, selected - but the wpa_state remains SCANNING and doesn't become COMPLETED. After a while (1.5 minutes), the device realizes that it's not really connected and tries to find another network:

```
Oct  3 07:09:50.819 **wpa_cli list_networks**  
Selected interface &apos;wlan0&apos;  
network id / ssid / bssid / flags  
0       MYEYE_AUTO      any     [DISABLED]  
1       Plazma  any     [DISABLED]  
2       Leumi_Guest     any     [DISABLED]  
8       **123\\xd7\\x9e\\xd7\\x9b\\xd7\\x99abc**    any  

Oct  3 07:09:50.854 **wpa_cli scan_results**  
Selected interface &apos;wlan0&apos;  
bssid / frequency / signal level / flags / ssid  
b2:22:7a:91:85:e5       2437    -65     [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS][P2P]  DIRECT-E5-HP OfficeJet Pro 8020  
5e:dc:7a:5a:88:9b       2462    -33     [ESS]   **123\xd7\x9e\xd7\x9b\xd7\x99abc**  
20:58:69:23:89:48       2462    -79     [ESS]   Leumi_Guest  
20:58:69:a3:89:48       2462    -79     [ESS]   Plazma  

Oct  3 07:09:51.127 **wpa_cli select_network 8**  

Oct  3 07:09:51.277 **wpa_cli list_networks**  
Selected interface &apos;wlan0&apos;  
network id / ssid / bssid / flags  
0       MYEYE_AUTO      any     [DISABLED]  
1       Plazma  any     [DISABLED]  
2       Leumi_Guest     any     [DISABLED]  
8       **123\\xd7\\x9e\\xd7\\x9b\\xd7\\x99abc**    any     **[CURRENT]**  

Oct  3 07:10:15.381 **wpa_cli status**  
Selected interface &apos;wlan0&apos;  
wpa_state=SCANNING  
ip_address=192.168.72.3  
p2p_device_address=34:e1:d1:a7:19:62  
address=34:e1:d1:a7:19:62  
uuid=9f4c27f1-a49d-5486-8821-465bc569b9ea
```

Is there any reason why this is happening?
What does the wpa-supplicant "need" in order to change wpa_state from SCANNING to COMPLETED?
PLEASE help with ideas.

Thanks,
Mechi

Comment: It's not really <code> but this was the only way I could post the question...

Comment: It seems you have double escaping with `\\`? An other possible problem: are you sure about the canonical UTF-8 encoding of your script? Apple is known not to use combining characters (so a different normalization form of Unicode).

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazzi
 This is the way wpa_cli shows the network names...                  wpa_cli v2.7
Copyright (c) 2004-2018, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi> and contributors

This software may be distributed under the terms of the BSD license.
See README for more details.


Selected interface 'wlan0'

Interactive mode

> list_networks 
network id / ssid / bssid / flags
0 MYEYE_AUTO any 
1 Plazma any 
2 Leumi_Guest any 
3 OrCam_WIFI any 
4 123=Mechi_abc any 
5 123\\xd7\\x9e\\xd7\\x9b\\xd7\\x99abc any 
6 123\\xd7\\x9e\\xd7\\x9b\\xd7\\x99abc any

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazzi  The actual wpa_supplicant.conf is:

Comment: cat wpa_supplicant.conf 
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1
bgscan="simple:30:-45:300"

network={
 ssid="MYEYE_AUTO"
 psk="see4yourself"
}

network={
 ssid="Plazma"
 key_mgmt=NONE
}

network={
 ssid="Leumi_Guest"
 key_mgmt=NONE
}

network={
 ssid="OrCam_WIFI"
 psk="1q2w3e4r"
}

network={
 ssid="123=Mechi_abc"
 key_mgmt=NONE
}

network={
 ssid="123\xd7\x9e\xd7\x9b\xd7\x99abc"
 key_mgmt=NONE
}

network={
 ssid="123\xd7\x9e\xd7\x9b\xd7\x99abc"
 key_mgmt=NONE
}

Comment: This may be the problem...though how to fix it? Should I take off the quotes in the conf file? I will definitely try this, but what will happen with the actual text?

Comment: And if you put the exact characters (encoded UTF-8) in such configuration file, without escaping? In such case, we can derive that the error is in the interface (so easier to fill a bug and get the fix)

Comment: It worked when the name in the conf file is all HEX characters. Now the problem is - why doesn't wpa_supplicant save the names of the found/scanned networks in a way that can be used to connect to them?

Comment: network={
 ssid=313233d79ed79bd799616263
 key_mgmt=NONE
 disabled=1
}

Comment: in wpa_cli - when list_networks:

Comment: 5 123\xd7\x9e\xd7\x9b\xd7\x99abc any [CURRENT]

Comment: <pre>&gt; status
bssid=5e:dc:7a:5a:88:9b
freq=2462
**ssid=123\xd7\x9e\xd7\x9b\xd7\x99abc**
id=5
mode=station
pairwise_cipher=NONE
group_cipher=NONE
key_mgmt=NONE
**wpa_state=COMPLETED**
ip_address=192.168.251.8
p2p_device_address=34:e1:d1:a7:19:62
address=34:e1:d1:a7:19:62
uuid=9f4c27f1-a49d-5486-8821-465bc569b9ea</pre>

Comment: file a bug report! Things are fixed only if developers know the problem (and they have time to fix, but this seems a simple fix).

Comment: I've been trying to see if this bug exists in the lates release - 2.10. And it does. I've also been trying to figure out how to open a BUG in the wpa_supplicant. I've wasted a whole day trying to figure out how to file this bug. I have logs of wpa_supplicant and wpa_cli...but have no idea where to send them...

Answer (score 0):

If an SSID has characters/symbols other than ASCII printable characters under 0x7F, the full SSID must be supplied as HEX.
In my example above, use

```
set_network X ssid 313233d79ed79bd799616263
```

It may not always be displayed with the correct symbols, and only using UTF-8 encoding, but it will be possible to connect to the network.

Comment: It seems this is a bug...hopefully later versins will not need this workaround